# fourier series expansions

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-series, sobolev-spaces

If someone could help me out with this problem and/or direct me to a proof somewhere I would appreciate it. Is there a name for such a proof so that I can look it up? I tried bounds on norm of Fourier Series and other similar searches.

Comment: Help you out with what problem? A name for what proof? It is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Oh very sorry. I got my answer already at a different place and I was trying to delete this but it wouldn’t let me. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rough Sketch**: 
Naively, you have
\begin{align}
f- f_N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{|n|\geq N} \hat f(n)e^{inx}.
\end{align}
In particular, the $j$th derivative is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{d^j}{dx^j}(f-f_N) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{|n|\geq N} (in)^j\hat f(n)e^{inx}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\left\|f-f_N \right\|^2_{L^2([0, 2\pi])}+\left\| \frac{d^j}{dx^j}(f-f_N)\right\|^2_{L^2([0, 2\pi])} =& \sum_{|n|\geq N} (1+n^{2j})|\hat f(n)|^2\\
=&\ \sum_{|n|\geq N} (1+n^{2j})(1+n^{2(s-j)})(1+n^{2(s-j)})^{-1}|\hat f(n)|^2\\
\leq&\ C\sum_{|n|\geq N} (1+|n|^{s-j})^{-2}(1+n^{2s})|\hat f(n)|^2 \\
\leq&\ C(1+N^{s-j})^{-2}\sum_{|n|\geq N} (1+n^{2s})|\hat f(n)|^2
\end{align}
since $|n| \geq N$.

**Additional Remark:** Let us note for $x, y\geq 1$
\begin{align}
(1+x)(1+y)  = 1+x+y+xy \leq 3(1+xy).
\end{align}